# JavaScript initialization before Polymer element registration

Tags: javascript, object, initialization, polymer-1.0

Moving from `Polymer` **v0.5** to **v1.0** the registration process of `Polymer elements` seems to be different. Before `Polymer v1.0` we could execute JavaScript code from `index.html` to initialize all needed objects in our `Polymer elements`. This is a very important detail because the `data-binding` in `Polymer` **ONLY** works correct when the bounded objects are initialized **FIRST**. This means the following:

For example if you want to bind an object in your `Polymer element` with `{{ }}` or `[[ ]]`, the object **must** be defined before the `Polymer element` registration! See:

```
<dom-module id="my-elem">
  <template>
    <div>This should be my bounded object: <b>{{obj.name}}</b></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
    is: 'my-elem',
    ready: function () {
      // Global initialized object!!!
      // app.obj ==> app.obj = { name: 'Great', info: 'Additional info!!!' };
      this.obj = app.obj;
    }
    ...      
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem is that if the `Polymer element` is registered **BEFORE** `app.obj` is initialized (in the example above `this.obj` is `undefined` at the time of `Polymer element` registration) then **NO** notification will be executed and no update provided even when `app.obj` is **NOT** `undefined` later on.

So in cases like that we need to initialize all bounded object first before we can use them with `{{ }}` or `[[ ]]`.

Is our approach totally wrong??? Any suggestions???

Comment: I'm battling with a very similar issue at the moment. Have you found an acceptable way to handling this?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, instead of `this.obj = app.obj;` in a `ready` function, I would add an event listener that would listen to an event fired when `app.obj` loads and then sets the binding:

```
ready: function() {
  var that = this;
  this.addEventListener('app-obj-loaded', function() {that.obj=app.obj});
}
```

Comment: How do I trigger or send an `app-obj-loaded` event from JavaScript?

Comment: There are different ways you can fire a custom event, but I would use [Polymer.Base.fire](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html#utility-functions).

Comment: Using [Polymer.Base.fire](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html#utility-functions) is only possible from inside Polymer context. In my case I retrieve the object from `Firebase` which is coming asynchronous and occurs in JavaScript context. IMO it make no sense to mix up UI components with the data layer. So I need the other way round to notify my Polymer UI components about changes which occurs in JavaScript.

Comment: 1. `Polymer` is a globally defined variable so it can be accessed from anywhere outside a polymer element. 2. Polymer is not only for UI, e.g. there is also Polymer elements for [Firebase](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element). 3. If you don't want to use `Polymer.Base.fire`, you can use [JQuery's api](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [vanilla javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case but worked without worrying about async.
Just define the property explicitly should work.

```
properties: {
  obj: {
    type: Object,
    value: {}
  }
}
```

If that won't work, try specifying `observer` and define a function that handles the `obj` properly.

```
properties: {
  obj: {
    type: Object,
    value: {},
    observer: 'loaded'
  }
}
```

Comment: These two suggestions didn't work for me. Corresponding to the [data-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) documentation I have to use one of the helper functions `notifyPath(path, value)` or `set(path, value)` to inform the system, that `obj` has changed. In my case I have to do it inside JavaScript where my asynchronous `Firebase` function call retrieves the object.

Comment: So it looks like changes to any sub-properties assigned as bound attribute requires such implementation.
Indeed, this is the doc of what you described https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding .
Thanks for sharing update.